# Determining Values of p for Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose we have the following series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{n^p+1}$

How would I go about determining which values of p make this series converge? Any guidance in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: How would you classify this series? What does the test for this type require to show convergence?

Comment: Perhaps an alternating series test. In which case, we need to find values of p for which our series converges by p-series test?

Comment: If it's an alternating series, a weaker condition than $p$-series test is needed...

Comment: I believe we would just want to find all values of p for which a_n goes to 0.

Comment: Right. So for which values of $p$ does $n^p+1$ outrace $n^2$?

Comment: For all values of p $\geq$ 2.

Comment: Almost; does $p=2$ work?

Comment: The absolute value of the general term also has to be decreasing.

Comment: So for all values of p>2.

Comment: The only issue I'm having with this is that for the alternating series test in my textbook, my conclusion would be that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} a_n$ converges, but here we have $(-1)^n$.

Comment: But $\ \sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^na_n= -\sum_{n=1}^m(-1)^{n+1}a_n\ $, so the first series converges as $\ m\rightarrow\infty\ $ if and only if the second does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive $p$ do a limit comparison test with 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{n^p}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nn^{2-p}.$$ The case $p=0$ is trivial. For negative $p$ let $q=-p.$ The series is 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{\frac{1}{n^q}+1}$$. Do a limit comparison test with $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nn^2}{1}$$ 
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nn^2$$